# Adding a list of acronyms to front matter file from separate file?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I've been fighting with this for too long - time to ask for help.

I am trying to create a list of acronyms for my thesis - Ideally I'd like the acronym definitions to be in a separate file so they are easier to find (instead of in main.tex). Is there a way to print the glossary (acronyms) in a separate file too (heading matches the rest of the front matter)? I'm not getting an error... I just get nothing. Looked to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436204/loading-glossaries-from-separate-file-using-texstudio) question for help but no luck.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
% margins and spacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%other stuff

%glossary
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{acronyms} %tried with acronyms.tex too

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\input{abbreviations}
\end{document}
```

Abbreviations file (where I want them to be printed) (abbreviations.tex):

```
\begin{center}
    \large
    \textbf{List of Abbreviations}
    \vspace{.4cm}
    \hrule
\end{center}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
```

acronym file (where they are defined) (acronym.tex):

```
\newacronym{T1}{T1}{Test1}
\newacronym{T2}{T2}{Test2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally stumbled on the answer

```
%glossary
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nomain,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{acronyms}
\makenoidxglossaries
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
```

and in abbreviations.tex:

```
\glsaddall
\printnoidxglossary
```